get image to Folder
i have Access database to chose icon from shell32.dll
my database has form with button .when i press it Open Dialog has all icons in shell32.dll . and when i chose icon .... result made shortcut but I need image with extension (.png).
Can anybody  help me For adjust the code to Make image with extension (.png).
Option Compare Database

Private Type OSVERSIONINFO
    dwOSVersionInfoSize As Long
    dwMajorVersion As Long
    dwMinorVersion As Long
    dwBuildNumber As Long
    dwPlatformId As Long
    szCSDVersion As String * 128
End Type

Private Declare Function PickIconDlg Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "#62" (ByVal hwndOwner As Long, ByVal lpstrFile As String, ByVal nMaxFile As Long, lpdwiIndex As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare Function GetVersionEx Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetVersionExA" (lpVersionInformation As OSVERSIONINFO) As Long
 
Private Declare Function GetSystemDirectory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetSystemDirectoryA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
 
Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT = 2
Private Const VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS = 1
Dim iIndex As Long
 
Public Function StripTerminator(ByVal strString As String) As String
  Dim intZeroPos As Integer
        intZeroPos = InStr(strString, Chr$(0))
        If intZeroPos > 0 Then
            StripTerminator = Left$(strString, intZeroPos - 1)
          Else
            StripTerminator = strString
        End If
End Function

Sub Shortcut(Application_Path, ShortcutName, IconLocation)
     Dim icoPath, objShortCut, strCurDir
    Dim objShell As Object
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
     strCurDir = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
    icoPath = CurrentProject.path & "\MyImages\"
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(icoPath & "\" & iIndex & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.IconLocation = IconLocation
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
 
Private Sub CmdSSImage_Click()
    Dim iFile As String  ' file that contains the icon
      ' index of the icon
    Dim sLen As Long  ' length of returned string
    Dim ovi As OSVERSIONINFO  ' Windows platform
    Dim retval As Long  ' return value
    ' If the computer is running Windows NT or 2000, all strings used with PickIconDlg must be converted into Unicode
    ovi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = Len(ovi)
    retval = GetVersionEx(ovi)
    ' Location of System directory
    iFile = Space(256)
    sLen = GetSystemDirectory(iFile, Len(iFile))
    iFile = Left(iFile, sLen)
    ' Default selection be the 2nd icon in SHELL32.dll.dll
    iFile = iFile & "\SHELL32.dll" & vbNullChar & Space(256)
    iIndex = 1
    ' Display the icon selection dialog. If Windows NT or 2000 is running, convert the string to and from Unicode
    If ovi.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT Then
        iFile = StrConv(iFile, vbUnicode)
    End If
    retval = PickIconDlg(Me.Hwnd, iFile, Len(iFile), iIndex)
    If ovi.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT Then
        iFile = StrConv(iFile, vbFromUnicode)
    End If
    ' Remove the terminating null and empty space
    iFile = StripTerminator(iFile)
    ' Draw the icon on Form1
    If retval <> 0 Then
        Text1 = iFile & ", " & iIndex
     Call Shortcut("11", "12", "%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll" & "," & iIndex)
     Text2 = iIndex
    End If
End Sub

